# sort meta_value $args=array(

Tags: arrays, sorting, advanced-custom-fields, args

i have a "table" that i'm trying to sort.
I created an ACF (=> placement).
The list goes from 1 to 10

The sorting works so far, but only from positions 2 to 9.
How do I now get 1 and 10?

```
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key' => 'platzierung',
'meta_value' => '10',
'meta_compare' => '>'
);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are your current and expected output?

Comment: I'm missing positions 1 and 10 in my list ...?!?  https://ibb.co/r7sZfPt

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MrThiemann/3b80930ed623d291d18d81b1cfa1b53e